# How to sort apps in Launchpad view?

Tags: macos, launchpad

I'm looking for a quick/easy way to organize my apps in Launchpad view. I know of the drag & drop method, but I would like to be able to sort by date, name, etc. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Launchpad Cleaner](http://zoltanb.co.uk/launchpadcleaner-is-retiring/) is a free alternative. It's no longer supported, but it continues to work just fine.